# C malloc a struct from its typedef

Tags: c, struct

Given the following struct

```
struct foo
{
  int b;
  int a;
  int r;
};
```

I want to create a new type from this struct, like following

```
typedef struct foo * foo_t;
```

That is to say that `foo_t` is supposed to equal a pointer of `struct foo`.
So `struct foo *var;` <=> `foo_t var;`

Why am I not able to malloc this struct from its type?

`foo_t var = malloc(sizeof(*foo_t));` throws an error at the compilation time

> error: expected expression before `foo_t`
>       foo_t var = malloc(sizeof((***_**foo_t)));

Comment: foo_t equals to a pointer. we need to malloc the size of the struct, not the pointer

Comment: ... and this is exactly why I don't like hiding pointers behind typedefs. :-)

Comment: I'm making oriented object C, I prefer to force to use pointers ;)

Comment: I don't think what I'm doing is that bad: https://gist.github.com/Romain-P/dd16dd4f1102c36d170c5e41d989c6b9

Comment: `sizeof *((foo_t) NULL)` would do. :-)

Comment: `sizeof((*_foo_t)));` (of the error message) is also a problem as `_foo_t` is not defined.  Best to post true code.

Comment: there is no _ in my source code, I added this to represent the selected char of the compiler

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `sizeof`'s operand must be either an expression or a parenthesized type name. `*foo_t` is neither.

I strongly recommend against hiding pointers behind typedefs. However, you can do the following:

```
foo_t var = malloc(sizeof *var);
```

`var` is not a type, so `*var` is a valid expression.

Comment: you need to add parentheses at `sizeof(*var)`

Comment: @Bizzu No, I don't.

Answer (score 0):

You must alloc a portion of memory of size **sizeof(struct foo)** for a variable with type foo_t and not of size sizeof(*foo_t). With the function malloc you alloc a portion of memory (of a determinate input size) that the pointer points to. Your variable **var** is type foo_t, that is, a pointer to a **struct foo** structure.
So the correct syntax for the allocation of variable **var** is:

```
foo_t var=malloc(sizeof(struct foo));
```